# Change join query to laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have a mysql query

```
SELECT a.`head_id` AS "Headid",a.`name` AS "HeadName", b.`id` AS "Emp_ID",b.`name` AS "Emp_name" FROM users a join users b ON a.id=b.head_id where a.`head_id`=63 or b.`id`=63
```

How can i convert this query to laravel?

```
$users = DB::table('users a')
            ->join('users b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.head_id')

            ->select('a.head_id as Headid','a.name AS HeadName','b.name AS Emp_name','b.name AS Emp_name')
            ->get();
```

but bad luck this is not working.please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query builder looks fine just add where filters as per your plain query

```
$users = DB::table('users as a')
            ->join('users as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.head_id')
            ->select('a.head_id as Headid','a.name AS HeadName','b.name AS Emp_name','b.name AS Emp_name')
            ->where('a.head_id', '=', 63)
            ->orWhere('b.id','=', 63)
            ->get();
```

Comment: @M khalid junaid thanks for the reply but i got an error like 'admin.users a' not exist..query like select `a`.`head_id` as `Headid`, `a`.`name` as `HeadName`, `b`.`name` as `Emp_name`, `b`.`name` as `Emp_name` from `users a` inner join `users b` on `a`.`id` = `b`.`head_id` where `a`.`head_id` = 63 or `b`.`id` = 63 and if i remove single quotes from `users a` it will work

Comment: @Ezra try with as keyword `users as a`